# Elasticsearch Stemmer Override Token Filter not working when usind rules path

Tags: elasticsearch, overriding, porter-stemmer

i have a problem when using the Stemmer Override Token Filter with a file with all the rules. It doesn´t work! When using the rules inline it works properly. Has anyone an idea why is that so?

not working example:

```
"protwords": { "type": "stemmer_override", "rules_path" : "analysis/protwords.txt" }
```

working example:

```
"protwords": { "type": "stemmer_override", "rules" : [ "jacke=>jacke", "jacken=>jacke", ] }
```

ES Version 1.7.1

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure `analysis/protwords.txt` is inside your elasticsearch config folder and restart elasticsearch.

This is the only thing I can think of.
I hope this helps!

Comment: thank you but it is in the right location. A restart is not needed. close/open index should be enough. But i found the problem. I have saved the file as ANSI encoding, but it must be utf-8 :)